# REST server returns HTTP 404 error powered by Jetty, How to find server log entries?

Tags: java, rest, fuseesb

I have a REST application deployed in FUSE ESB 6.1. There are many services exposed to the external clients.
The issue is, Sometimes clients receive HTTP 404 Not Found with the following html.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /context/api/service1. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
</body>
</html>
```

I can see this is due to a wrong service name.

But i can't find any related log entries in server logs. 
Is there any option to see these Jetty Error details in the REST server? Possibly any Jetty logs ?

Comment: You're looking at the log. What more are you expecting? This is no different than asking for an image that doesn't exist. You get a 404 not found. Since this happens frequently, web servers don't typically log this sort of client error. Do you want to tell the server to log these types of errors?

Comment: I'm guessing that it's simply the code (either server-side or client-side depending on how you create the URLs) that doesn't create the correct URL for the REST endpoint.

Comment: Yes, its due to the wrong url. But how can i turn on the server log to record this. I need to record this for a specific time, to understand client activities.

Comment: Do you use logging.properties when executing ? You might need to change the logging level. Try setting it to FINEST. Is your verb correct (GET versus POST for example)

Answer (score 1):

As with any servlet container, you can redirect 404 errors to a JSP, servlet, whatever, and simply log the URL yourself.

From the [Jetty documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/custom-error-pages.html):

> Error code example:
>
> ```
> <error-page>
>   <error-code>404</error-code>
>   <location>/jspsnoop/ERROR/404</location>
> </error-page>
> ```
>
> Exception example:
>
> ```
> <error-page>
>   <exception-type>java.io.IOException</exception-type>
>   <location>/jspsnoop/IOException</location>
> </error-page>
> ```

You can also catch 404 errors that happen outside your application context:

> **Server level 404 error**
>
> It is possible to get a page not found when a request is made to the
>   server for a resource that is outside of any registered contexts. As
>   an example, you have a domain name pointing to your public server IP,
>   yet no context is registered with Jetty to serve pages for that
>   domain. As a consequence, the server, by default, gives a listing of
>   all contexts running on the server.
>
> One of the quickest ways to avoid this behavior is to create a catch
>   all context. Create a "root" web app mapped to the "/" URI, and use
>   the index.html redirect to whatever place with a header directive.